# How to invoke method which using c++ operate

Tags: c++

I wante to invoke method `operator id () const` below ,which writing by C++ opreate

```
struct CKBoxedValue {
  CKBoxedValue() noexcept : __actual(nil) {};

  // Could replace this with !CK::is_objc_class<T>
  CKBoxedValue(bool v) noexcept : __actual(@(v)) {};
  CKBoxedValue(int8_t v) noexcept : __actual(@(v)) {};
  CKBoxedValue(uint8_t v) noexcept : __actual(@(v)) {};
  CKBoxedValue(int16_t v) noexcept : __actual(@(v)) {};
  CKBoxedValue(uint16_t v) noexcept : __actual(@(v)) {};
  CKBoxedValue(int32_t v) noexcept : __actual(@(v)) {};
  CKBoxedValue(uint32_t v) noexcept : __actual(@(v)) {};
  CKBoxedValue(int64_t v) noexcept : __actual(@(v)) {};
  CKBoxedValue(uint64_t v) noexcept : __actual(@(v)) {};
  CKBoxedValue(long v) noexcept : __actual(@(v)) {};
  CKBoxedValue(unsigned long v) noexcept : __actual(@(v)) {};
  CKBoxedValue(float v) noexcept : __actual(@(v)) {};
  CKBoxedValue(double v) noexcept : __actual(@(v)) {};
  CKBoxedValue(SEL v) noexcept : __actual([NSValue valueWithPointer:v]) {};
  CKBoxedValue(std::nullptr_t v) noexcept : __actual(nil) {};

  // Any objects go here
  CKBoxedValue(__attribute((ns_consumed)) id obj) noexcept : __actual(obj) {};

  // Define conversions for common Apple types
  CKBoxedValue(CGRect v) noexcept : __actual([NSValue valueWithCGRect:v]) {};
  CKBoxedValue(CGPoint v) noexcept : __actual([NSValue valueWithCGPoint:v]) {};
  CKBoxedValue(CGSize v) noexcept : __actual([NSValue valueWithCGSize:v]) {};
  CKBoxedValue(UIEdgeInsets v) noexcept : __actual([NSValue valueWithUIEdgeInsets:v]) {};

  operator id () const {
    return __actual;
  };

private:
  id __actual;

};
```

Comment: Something like `CKBoxedValue cbv; id y = cbv();`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ
I do this `CKBoxedValue box = CKBoxedValue(); id v = box();` but compiler throw `Type 'CKBoxedValue' does not provide a call operator` error

Comment: Since it's an implicit conversion operator it should be just `id v = box;` (without any parenthesis)

Comment: This thing is called "type cast operator", which should help you for further research.

Comment: @UnholySheep it's right,thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the user-defined conversion function `operator id() const;` like any other member function:

```cpp
// (Assuming `x` is some value of type `CKBoxedValue`)

x.operator id();
```

But it is usually called during a type conversion, for example:

```cpp
// Explicit conversions:
id(x)
static_cast<id>(x)
id value(x);

// Implicit conversions:
// With `void function_taking_an_id(id arg);`
function_taking_an_id(x)
id value = x;
```